# Default date (today) bootstrap datepicker IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

Out of the box datepicker highlights the correct default date (today) in Chrome. However, in IE 11 it incorrectly picks the date 03/12/2015 (way off in the future).

I am using the following code

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

<div class="input-group date datepicker">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control" }
</div>
```

Any ideas to combat this?

Answer (score 1):

Try add: `userCurrent: false`

Full Code:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    language: 'nl',
    useSeconds: false,
    useCurrent: false,
    showToday: true
});
```